# What can cause table columns to end up narrower than their definition?

Tags: html, css

I've got a CSS rule:

```
#map td {
    border: medium none;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 32px;
}
```

And I have a table inside an element called `map`.  Each cell of the table is supposed to contain an image that's 32x32 pixels in size.  But when I render it, either in Firefox or in Chrome, the map grid ends up severely squished under certain circumstances.

Examining it in Firebug, I find that the styles are all applied correctly, with the `#map td` style as the dominant rule for the cells in question, but when I look at the Computed tab, it gives the `width` property (under "Box Model") as 14.6167px.  If I expand the `width` node, the only thing under it is: `#map td      32 px`, so I'm a bit at a loss as to what's causing all of my columns to be so much narrower than 32 px.

I'm sorry that this isn't much to go by, but I'm still fairly new to CSS so I don't know a lot of the right questions to ask.  Does anyone know what can cause something like this to happen, and how I can deal with it?

**UPDATE:**  After a bit of experimenting, trying to narrow it down to a simple, reproducible test case, it seems to be that the sidebar div is "squeezing" the main div and there's not enough room,  so the browser is making the main one narrower, because when I remove the sidebar, everything goes back to the correct width.  So now the question is, how do I set this up so that the width of the table is *enforced* as described and can't be squeezed by other elements to the side of it?

Comment: You'll want to provide an excerpt of the table markup with the image in question.

Comment: @BoltClock: See my edit.  I tried to prepare one and found that the problem was actually with the sidebar.

Comment: See if you can put together a test case that simulates the sidebar interfering with the table sizing when it is present.

Comment: plese create a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your td/th with a defined width like you've already done.

For your table, set the layout to fixed, and you'll also have to define a fixed width as well.

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 64px;
    }
```